# How to find the difference between two dates in same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff, sliding-window

I have a table SO_STATUS that writes a record for each status change for a service order (we'll call the Service_Order_ID "Job_ID").  Job_ID references SERVICE_ORDER table.  When the service order is initialized, a record is written for that status type of "open" (StatusType 2) which shows the datetime.  Then another record is written in the status table for when it is "in progress" (StatusType 1).  And also when the service order is "closed", another record written in the status table (StatusType 3).  There are also other status types that may happen, but these are the most common.  The data in the SO_STATUS table looks like this:

```
id            Date                Job_ID  StatusTypeID  EmployeeID
1     2012-01-01 09:05:00.000       51        2             5
2     2012-01-01 10:00:00.000       52        2            12
3     2012-01-01 10:01:00.000       51        1             5
4     2012-01-01 12:15:00.000       53        2             8
5     2012-01-01 12:16:00.000       51        3             5
6     2012-01-01 13:00:00.000       52        1            12
7     2012-01-01 14:00:00.000       52        3            12
8     2012-01-01 14:15:00.000       53        1             8
9     2012-01-01 15:00:00.000       54        2            11
10    2012-01-01 16:30:00.000       53        3             8
11    2012-01-01 15:00:00.000       54        1            11
12    2012-01-01 16:30:00.000       54        3            11
```

I need to be able to find the time elapsed between each status change of each Job_ID.  Essentially, the duration of time spent from open to close for the job.

Output would look something like (EmployeeName would be referenced from the EMPLOYEE table):

```
Job_ID       Duration    EmployeeName
  51         03:11:00        Kyle
  52         04:00:00        Chris
  53         04:15:00        Fred
  54         01:30:00        John
```

How would I go about getting this type of output?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (anyparticularunit, ' 2012-01-01 09:05:00.000', ' 2012-01-01 15:00:00.000')
```

**Go through following link for datediff:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Also follow this link to get different exmples:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=56126

Hope you will put further where conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This this one -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @duration TABLE 
(
      id BIGINT IDENTITY
    , [date] DATETIME
    , job_id INT
    , [status] VARCHAR(10)
    , employee_id INT
)

INSERT INTO @duration ([date], job_id, [status], employee_id)
VALUES
    ('2012-01-01 09:05:00.000', 51, 'open', 5),
    ('2012-01-01 10:00:00.000', 52, 'open', 12),
    ('2012-01-01 10:01:00.000', 51, 'inprogress', 5),
    ('2012-01-01 12:15:00.000', 53, 'open', 8),
    ('2012-01-01 12:16:00.000', 51, 'closed', 5),
    ('2012-01-01 13:00:00.000', 52, 'inprogress', 12),
    ('2012-01-01 14:00:00.000', 52, 'closed', 12),
    ('2012-01-01 14:15:00.000', 53, 'inprogress', 8),
    ('2012-01-01 15:00:00.000', 54, 'open', 11),
    ('2012-01-01 16:30:00.000', 53, 'closed', 8),
    ('2012-01-01 15:00:00.000', 54, 'inprogress', 11),
    ('2012-01-01 16:30:00.000', 54, 'closed', 11)

SELECT 
      job_id
    , employee_id
    , work_time = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MAX([date]) - MIN([date]), 114) 
FROM @duration
GROUP BY job_id, employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF to return the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
 SELECT Job_ID,
 DATEDIFF(day, (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM YOUTABLE WHERE Job_ID=k.Job_ID),(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM YOUTABLE WHERE Job_ID=k.Job_ID)),
 (SELECT EmployeeName FROM EmployeeTABLE WHERE EmployeeID=k.EmployeeID)) FROM YOUTABLE k
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database is Oracle, you can do like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID, MAX(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_ID)-MIN(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_ID) AS Duration FROM TA JOIN TB .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created some custom code to create dat and time difference, using datediff function and dividing with certain numbers to generate hours, minutes and seconds:

```
SELECT 
    Job_ID,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)) / 3600 AS VARCHAR)
    + ':' + CAST((DATEDIFF(second, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)) % 3600) / 60 AS VARCHAR)
    + ':' + CAST(((DATEDIFF(second, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)) % 3600) % 60)  AS VARCHAR)
FROM YOUTABLE 
GROUP BY Job_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try query given below:

```
Select t1.Job_ID,
Convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(HH,Min(t1.JobDate),tbl.MaxDate))+' : '+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s,Min(t1.JobDate),tbl.MaxDate) % 3600/60)+' : '+Convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s,Min(t1.JobDate),
tbl.MaxDate) % 60) MinDate,t1.EmployeeName From SO_STATUS t1
Inner join (Select Max(JobDate) MaxDate, job_id From SO_STATUS  Group By Job_Id)tbl on t1.Job_ID=tbl.Job_ID
Inner Join EMPLOYEE e On e.EmployeeID=t1.EmployeeID
Group By t1.EmployeeName,tbl.MaxDate,t1.Job_ID
Order By t1.Job_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

## Difference between two dates of different tables which has datetime format.

SELECT t1.Column_Names,

CONVERT(varchar(10),t1.CreatedOn,103)

AS CreatedOn FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2

ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE CAST (t1.CreatedOn as Date)

BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate.

> i have taken t1.CreatedOn as my table attribute which holds date.
>
> @fromdate and @todate to pass dates.